# Ajax_JQUERY and Laravel Controller?

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel, laravel-blade, laravel-controller

I am new in Laravel,i need to add edit and show button via  in Controller here is my controller

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use DB;

class LiveSearch extends Controller
{
    function index() {
        return view('live_search');
    }

    function action(Request $request) {
     if($request->ajax()) {
        $output = '';
        $query = $request->get('query');

        if($query != '') {
           $data = DB::table('students')
             ->where('student_name', 'like', '%'.$query.'%')
             ->orWhere('student_address', 'like', '%'.$query.'%')
             ->orWhere('student_registration', 'like', '%'.$query.'%')
             ->orderBy('student_name', 'desc')
             ->get();
        } else {
           $data = DB::table('students')
             ->orderBy('student_name', 'desc')
             ->get();
        }

        $total_row = $data->count();

        if($total_row > 0) {
           foreach($data as $row) {
              $output .= '
                <tr>
                   <td>'.$row->student_name.'</td>
                   <td>'.$row->student_address.'</td>
                   <td>'.$row->student_registration.'</td>
                   <td>'.$row->id.'</td>
                   <td>' <a  href="{{ URL::to(student/ ".$row->id." /edit) }}">Edit</a>'
                         <a href={{ URL::to(student/  '.$row->id.') }}>Show</a></td>
                </tr>';
           }
        } else {
           $output = '
             <tr>
                <td align="center" colspan="5">No Data Found</td>
             </tr>';
        }

        $data = array(
          'table_data'  => $output,
          'total_data'  => $total_row
        );

        echo json_encode($data);
     }
   }
}
```

**PROBLEM** Here is the problem i dont know how to add id with edit button and show  along with bootstrap class btn btn success//
it fetches all the data from student table but i don't know how to add  could you pleaes guied me what to do, i search a lot but it not solve my problem thanks

Comment: What are the errors you are getting?

Comment: i use the following code <td><a href="{{url(student/'.$row->id.'/edit)}}"> EDIT</a></td> ,, when i click the edit it show diffrent type of URL and not go to edit page . the url after clicking the edit http://localhost:8000/%7B%7Burl(student/3/edit)%7D%7D

Comment: Add the routes in your post.

Comment: Route::get('/live_search', 'LiveSearch@index');
Route::get('/live_search/action', 'LiveSearch@action')->name('live_search.action');

Comment: here is the example which i read just to make two <a> one for edit and one for Show i am new in laravel and programming https://www.webslesson.info/2018/04/live-search-in-laravel-using-ajax.html

Comment: The given route and the route in your post is different

Comment: yes you are right , Once i click the URL should be like localhost:8000/student/1/edit and Page Not found , but if we check the url it not getting ID here is the url localhost:8000/%7B%7Burl(student/3/edit)%7D%7D

Comment: the problem is here while adding value to <a href > other stuff work perfectly but not <a>  <tr>
         <td>'.$row->student_name.'</td>
         <td>'.$row->student_address.'</td>
         <td>'.$row->student_registration.'</td>
         <td>'.$row->id.'</td>         
         <td><a href="{{url(student/'.$row->id.'/edit)}}"> EDIT</a></td>
         
        </tr>';

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is you are not passing the url correctly.

```
$output .= '
            <tr>
               <td>'.$row->student_name.'</td>
               <td>'.$row->student_address.'</td>
               <td>'.$row->student_registration.'</td>
               <td>'.$row->id.'</td>
               <td>
                   <a href="'.url("student/".$row->id."/edit").'">Edit</a>
                   <a href="'.url("student/".$row->id).'">Show</a>
               </td>
            </tr>';
```

If your url is named route, like this:

```
Route::get('/live_search', 'LiveSearch@index')->name('live.search');
```

You can specify like this too

```
route('live.search')
```

I'm not sure about your routes, change it if you have different route.

Comment: Thank you very much it work now with  <td><a href="'.url('student/'.$row->id).'/edit">Edit</a>
         <a href="'.url('student/'.$row->id).'">Show</a>
            </td>